# Android PAD: Play video from asset pack

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am currently developing an app, which has lots of videos in it. They all need to be locally saved because they need to be available offline.

Problem is that I am going over the 150MB limit for the Play Store.

I have now implemented Play Asset Delivery and have set up an asset pack. I moved all the Videos from RAW to that asset pack.

Now I am searching for a possibility to play the videos from the asset pack in a VideoView, or preferably with ExoPlayer.

I have tried the MediaPlayer approach, but that doesn't work, as the VideoView is always black when it starts.

I also thought that there might be path for the asset pack, like the base assets folder has ("assets:///video.mp4") but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
VideoView view = findViewById(R.id.video);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```

Comment: Not working because I can't use the raw folder.

Comment: oh! sorry playing mp4 from assets not possible

Comment: you should complress the video and move to raw filder